# How can I copy all objects in root directory but not subdirectories with aws s3 cp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I need to copy content inside a AWS S3 bucket root folder to another folder inside root.

I want copy all files in root (textfile1.txt etc) except other folders (folder1,folder2) in to the folder3.

What would be the aws s3 copy command for it?

```
/
folder1
folder2
textfile1.txt
textfile2.txt
--many other text files
folder3
```

Comment: So you want to copy `*.txt` files into folder3?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This command will copy all files from the root of the bucket, but will not copy any sub-folders:

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket s3://my-bucket/destination --recursive --exclude "*/*"
```

- `--recursive` causes it to copy all files and folders
- `--exclude "*/*"` prevents it from copying any objects with a `/` in the key (which is used to indicate a sub-folder)

See also:

- [Use of Exclude and Include Filters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)
- [aws s3 cp examples](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html#examples)

Comment: Note that this still enumerates every key in the bucket to find the keys that don't have `/` in them. Not a problem unless your bucket is huge and you don't want to wait though.